# Adding multiple simulation values from a monte carlo

Tags: python

I am trying to sum the values in Callpayoffs, as they represent the payoffs based on the last price which is generated in the prior path asset price loop. If I run 10 simulations, there should be 10 Callpayoffs based on the last price of each simulation path which has 252 price points. Unfortunately I'm not able to add up the values in the Callpayoffs list in any way so I can take the average Callpayoff over the 10 simulations. Would really appreciate any help - the below is a sample of print(sum(Callpayoffs). As you can see the code only divides the last value by 10, the number of simulations

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[16.651081469090343]
[14.076846993975735]
[9.483857458061152]
[5.357562042338017]
[6.09266787737144]
[0]
[27.85935401436157]

2.785935401436157 # this is the last value divided by no of 
simulations, but should be the sum of all values above divided by 
simulations


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import *


def Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt):
    return (1 + r * dt + v * sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(0,1))


# initial values
S = 100
v = 0.2
r = 0.05
T = 1
N = 252 # number of steps 
dt = 0.00396825
simulations = 10


for x in range(simulations):
    stream = [100]
    Callpayoffs = []
    t = 0
    for n in range(N):
        s = stream[t] * Generate_asset_price(S,v,r,dt)
        stream.append(s)
        t += 1
    Callpayoffs.append(max(stream[-1] - S,0)) 
    plt.plot(stream)
    print(Callpayoffs)

print(sum(Callpayoffs))
(sum(Callpayoffs)) / float(simulations)
```

Comment: You probably want `Callpayoffs` outside your first `for` loop if you'r hoping to collect values in it. As it is, you create a new array every loop.

Comment: `Callpayoffs = []` before `for` loops

Comment: thanks so much thats solved the issue!!